# what is the slope of the tangent at the point (4,f(4))

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Consider $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$ what is the slope of the tangent line to the graph of f at the point (4,f(4)). Just asking: am I doing this wrong?

$$f'(a)= \lim_{h\to a}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

f'(4)= 4 + ${\sqrt 4}$ =4+2=6 --> f"(a)=6

y - f(a) = f'(a)(x-a)

y - (${\sqrt 4}$) = (6)(x - 4)

y - (-4) = (6)(x - 4)

y + 4 = 6x - 24 + x + 4

y = 7x - 24

= -17x

Comment: You can either use $f'(a) = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ or $f'(a) = \lim_\limits{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. You want to make sure you get the definition right. What exactly did you do on the second line? (Clearly $f(a) \color{red}{\neq f'(a)}$.) Also, are you supposed to use this definition to find $f'(4)$ or can you use derivative rules?

Comment: i think use this definition to find f'(4) i used the the tangent line equation i think           y-f(a) = f'(a)(x-a)

Comment: You should try it again using the right definition and see if you can get it right. You're supposed to get $f'(4) = \dfrac{5}{4}$.

Comment: yes thank you i got it!! does this mean the domains of f and f' are the same?

Comment: Not necessarily. Note that $f$ is defined at $x = 0$, while $f'$ isn't. Since you got it, why not edit your question and show your work?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are using is the alternate definition which is fine to use. The derivative should come out as $1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. I personally would suggest plug in the function expressions to the limit definition, simplify, then plug in 4 as your x-value. You should get $\frac{5}{4}$. After that, plug $\frac{5}{4}$ for $m$ into point slope form: $y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$ and substitute $x_1$ and $y_1$ for (4, f(4)). Finally, use Algebra to convert point slope form into slope intercept form.

Answer (score 0):

The definition is:
$$f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}$$
Start with that. In your case, $a = 4$.